# How to change sharepoint database config

Tags: sharepoint

Our sharepoint application database ip is now changed, (It is not under my control)

Since it is changed i cannot connect to my web site and cannot connect to central administration.

So how can i find the place where the database ip/name is stored so that i can change the db configration.

i have checked all the web.config files under iis->explore folder
i have changed the 'dsn' key under path

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\Secure\ConfigDb

Comment: Run the sharepoint configuration wizard and set the database server

Answer (score 1):

You could change the database instance of the application with the SharePoint Management Shell.

If you want to change all application at once you could run following powershell code:

```
# ForEach schleife
ForEach( $db in get-spdatabase) { 
$db.ChangeDatabaseInstance("newDataBaseAddress")
$db.Update()
}
```

If you want to change only one application you can run following code:

```
$db = get-spdatabase -identity id
$db.ChangeDatabaseInstance("newDataBaseAddress")
$db.Update()
```

To get the ids of the applications simply run:

```
get-spdatabase
```

To change database server for Central Administration if WSS_Admin is depending on old database run following code:

```
$centralAdmin=Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | ? {$_.DisplayName -match ‘SharePoint Central Administration’}
$good=Get-SPWebApplication -identity placeHereTheIdOfAnApplicationThatHasTheCorrectDatabaseInstance
$centralAdmin.Parent.DefaultDatabaseInstance=$good.Parent.DefaultDatabaseInstance
$centralAdmin.Parent.Update()
$centralAdmin.Update()
```

I hope i could help.